# Doctrine Migrations with more than one databases/schemas (in Symfony project)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I have a single data connection with two schemas configured in my Symfony 6 project:

```
Localhost
 - app
 - common
```

```xml
<doctrine:config>
    <doctrine:dbal dbname="app" url="%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%">
</doctrine:dbal>
```

Both schemas have a separate set of entity mapping.

- The `app` has mapping written in XML files. It's the old one.
- The `common` has mapping written using attributes. It's the new one. I was trying to create the first SQL table for it.

I have entity manager configured this way:

```xml
<doctrine:orm
    default-entity-manager="default"
    auto-generate-proxy-classes="true"
>
    <doctrine:entity-manager
        name="default"
        connection="default"
        naming-strategy="doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware"
        auto-mapping="false"
    >
        <doctrine:mapping
            name="App"
            alias="App"
            prefix="App\Entity"
            is-bundle="false"
            type="xml"
            dir="%kernel.project_dir%/config/doctrine"
        />
        <doctrine:mapping
            name="ModelCommon"
            alias="ModelCommon"
            prefix="MyCompany\ModelCommon\Entity"
            is-bundle="false"
            type="attribute"
            dir="%kernel.project_dir%/model/Entity"
        />
    </doctrine:entity-manager>
</doctrine:orm>
```

So here's the issue. The project before had only the `app` schema. So the database contains a couple of already integrated entities. I want to integrate the other `common` schema having only one entity (for now). **I have issues with generating a proper migrations for it.**

This is the new entity:

```php
namespace MyCompany\ModelCommon\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'category', schema: 'common')]
class Category
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $category_id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $category_name;
}
```

Whenever I'm trying to `doctrine:migrations:diff` or just `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`, I receive this information:

```
[OK] Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

Obviously, removing `schema: 'common'` from the entity results in proper query generated:

```sql
CREATE TABLE category (category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT [...]
```

I've already tried to manage the issue on multiple ways. Like, making a separate `<doctrine:connection ... />` or separate entity managers (one for each schema). Both ideas failed. Even with changing `dbname="app"` for `default_dbname="app"` in the DBAL configuration.

It would be even ideal to have two separate namespaces of migrations which would have no affect on each other. Like, migrating one schema would consider only one namespace. Though I had problems with implementing that idea as well.

Is there any particular way on how to manage with this problem? Thank you in advance for any help .

Answer (score 0):

List of options

`bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff -h`

Generate by entity manager name

`bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --env=dev --em=ModelCommon`

Generate by connection name

`bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --env=dev --conn=SomeConnection`

Comment: I'm fully aware of those options, but both doesn't work. If an entity has a `schema` defined, then such entity is not taken into consideration when generating schema SQL at all.